# Why Twilio receiving only blank body if we send images/media from my mobile via WhatsApp application?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

> [twilio] [twilio-whatsapp]

I have successfully integrated Whastsapp beta provided by twilio and sending and receiving text working perfectly. Moreover with the one trick I am also able to send images from twilio to whtasapp but reverse flow is not working.

**When I send media from mobile whatsapp application to twilio then twilio only receive black body.** *No text body no Media.*

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio API for WhatsApp doesn't yet support media. But it is being worked on.

I would still expect the text to come through, so if that's not the case then I recommend you contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and give them some message SIDs where this happened and they will alert the WhatsApp team.

Comment: Thanks for answer! However this is very disappointing that media sharing is not supported yet, there is no point of use without it. I mean what to do with only text? Even twilio sms/mms works more than it!

Comment: Well, the good news is that support for media is coming. It's just not here yet. Hopefully it arrives soon though, I know I'd like to build some things with it too.